# Same function required specific action

Tags: jquery

I have several content divs in a loop that contain a hidden div with a more button, on click of the more button it shows the hidden div.

The problem I am having is that when i click on the "more button" is shows all the hidden divs on each of the content divs. I need this to be specific to the content div it is in

The code I am using is:

```
$("a.ta-detail").click(function(){
  $(".ta-show-more").slideToggle(300, function() {
        $("a.ta-detail").text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Less" : "More");
    });
})
```

Thanks for any help in advance
Jonathan

Comment: please share your html sample also

Comment: the problem you have is that your "more" button seems to be in your hidden div

Comment: try to play with ids instead of class

Comment: Show your HTML. Without it we cant help.

Comment: <div class="ta-show-more">
<h3>Stayed July 2013</h3>
</div>
                                
<a class="btn black small shdw ta-detail">More</a>

Comment: still finding my feet on this website, will post accordingly going forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a.ta-detail").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).siblings(".ta-show-more").slideToggle(300, function() {
        var text = $(this).is(':visible')?"Less":"More";
        $this.text(text);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have as many open buttons as you have hidden div´s you could try something like :

```
$("a.ta-detail").click(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(".ta-show-more").eq(index).slideToggle(300, function() {
    $("a.ta-detail").text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Less" : "More");
});
})
```

that will only toggle the hidden div that equals the correct index